# Could Menubar object have hint on it's menu items?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

- Is there a way to show a hint on the menu items in **mx:Menubar** object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by "hint" mean the tooltip text that appears when you hover over an item, you might find [this page](http://www.jusfortechies.com/flex/display-tooltip-in-menubar.php) useful.